# Are non-homogenous equations always linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have an equation of the form Ax = b

And in a homogenous equation if $c_1+c_2+...+c_n = 0$ and none of the variables are parameterized by others, then an equation is linearly independent and has only the trivial solution.

So is this applicable to the case in which $b \not= 0$, because then wouldn't it be the same equation as Ax = 0, just with a translation of the solution vector instead?

Note that I haven't learned about determinants and other things yet, so I know linear independence can be determined using a determinant (from what I've seen) so I'm sorry if this seems to be an obvious question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not simply a translation of the solution.

Here I consider a square matrix $A$, to simplify.

Consider the columns of $A$. Solving the linear system $Ax=0$ means

- finding if there is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ that vanishes, e.g. $x_1A^{<1>}+\cdots+x_nA^{<n>}=0$
- finding the kernel of the endomorphism (linear map) $f$ represented by $A$. The kernel is only the null vector iff the image of the application is the whole space ([rank-nuillty theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)).

Therefore, when the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, every vector $b$ of the linear space is the image of some $x$, so the system $Ax=b$ has a solution (and it is actually unique).

However, when the columns of $A$ are **not** linearly independent, the image of the endomorphism represented by $A$ is not the whole space (the linear map is not surjective), which means for some vectors $b$ the system has no solution. For other values of $b$, thanks to the linear relation between the columns of $A$, you get infinitely many solutions, with parameters. And the solution is never unique: if $Ax=b$ for some $x$, then $A(x+y)=b$ for all $y\in\ker f$.

Comment: So then does that mean linear independence is a shared characteristic between a homogeneous equation and an inhomogeneous one where Ax both equal the same thing in both scenarios? For example, if I determine a homogenous equation Ax=0, to be linearly independent due to no free variables, would that mean that any inhomogeneous equation Ax=b where A and x are the same and $b \not= 0$ would also be linearly independent?

Comment: @DanLupu Linear independance is a property of the matrix, not of the system. So yes it applies to both $Ax=0$ and $Ax=b$, although not with the sames consequences ($Ax=0$ has always the solution $x=0$, whereas $Ax=b$ does not always have a solution). And yes, if the solution of $Ax=0$ is unique, the system $Ax=b$ has a unique solution (beware, that's assuming $A$ is square, if not you have to consider the dimension of $\mathrm{im}(f)$).

Comment: @DanLupu With a non-square $A$, i.e. a linear map $f: E\to F$ where $E$ and $F$ don't have the same dimension, then you have $\dim \ker f+\dim\mathrm{im}(f)=\dim E$, and not $\dim F$. And for instance if the system if overdetermined (more equations than variables), the system $Ax=0$ may have the unique solution $x=0$, but that does not mean $Ax=b$ has always a solution (the image of $f$ will have *at most* the dimension $\dim E<\dim F$).